# What does this message mean:"Please check the Tcl console output"?

Tags: vivado

I have tried to run this code, using Vivado 2014.4 but this error appeared to me:

**"[USF-XSim-62] 'compile' step failed with error(s). Please check the Tcl console output"**

the code:

[xorshift.vhd](https://github.com/cjameshuff/vhdlstuff/blob/master/xorshift.vhd)

[xorshift_tb.vhd](https://github.com/cjameshuff/vhdlstuff/blob/master/xorshift_tb.vhd)

What is the error in the code?

Comment: Did you check the Tcl console?

Comment: @melpomene, This is first time I use this software, could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I've never even heard of "Vivado" but I found some screenshots when I googled your error message.

Comment: Please include your code into your question. I'm not sure if xSim supports the `for ... use ... ` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved] Change the license of Vivado software.